# Why Firefox change my bootstrap datepicker style?

Tags: html, css, firefox, bootstrap-4

in a date input, in Chrome, Edge and others is ok

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" min='1900-01-01' name="birthDate" id="birthDate" required>
```

now, when i try on Firefox Explorer, it looks dark.

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmJ92.jpg)

[Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O44Qj.jpg)

Comment: Do you have dark mode enabled on Firefox or your computer?

Answer (score 0):

The style of the datapicker doesn't change with Bootstrap. You can only change the 'field' but not the popup where you can choose a date. But some browsers have their unique style for this popup. This is why you will see various changes when use different browsers. If you want to make a custom popup you can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wY2dao1hJms) link.

Hope it helps!